# JSON.Stringify() on big numbers alters the numeric value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a WCF service operation that returns an object with `long` and `List<string>` properties. When I test the operation in a WCF application, everything works fine and the values are correct. However, I need to be able to call the service using jQuery and JSON format. The value of the `long` property apparently changes when I read it back in the `OnSucceed` function.

After searching I've found that `JSON.stringify` changes big values. So in code like this:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(25001509088465005));
```

...it will show the value as `25001509088465004`.

What is happening?

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/tPKw7/

Comment: Please make your question more clear.

Comment: just Test the javascript code above and see what you have send and what JSON.stringify has returned.

Comment: Due to precision limit of javascripts Number type. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken

Comment: @Gaurav: the question is very clear. just try that out.

Comment: @Amir Mohsen: this has got nothing to do with JSON infact. Try this. `alert(25001509088465005);`

Comment: JSON.stringify convert a JSON object in array.
you can use JSON.parse instead of stringify function.
check that you have return a JSON object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript represents numbers using [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) double-precision (64 bit) format. As I understand it this gives you 53 bits precision, or fifteen to sixteen decimal digits. Your number has more digits than JavaScript can cope with, so you end up with an approximation.

Do you need to do maths operations on this big number? Because if its just some kind of ID you can return it as a string and avoid the problem.

Comment: yeah but i wanted to have it as long but finally I receive it as string and this is the end of that.

Comment: There is no "long" datatype in JavaScript, only Number.

Comment: Yes, I should have explicitly said "JavaScript represents _all_ numbers using..."

Comment: at last I used string instead of that 17 digits number and life is beautiful now