# JSON transfer of bigint: 12000000000002539 is converted to 12000000000002540?

Tags: javascript, json, biginteger

I'm transferring raw data like `[{id: 12000000000002539, Name: "Some Name"}]` and I'm getting the object `[{id: 12000000000002540, Name: "Some Name"}]` after parsing, for now server side converting id into string seems to help.
But is there a better way to transfer bigint data correctly?

Comment: You can't do something like `long long` in C if that is what you are asking. String is probably the better way to go.

Comment: This is essentially the same as this question from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8641668/615754. JavaScript can represent big numbers, but with only about 15 or 16 digits of precision.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812096/javascript-large-integer-round-because-precision-why

Comment: Does the question still relevant in 2023-2024???

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The value is actually *not* exceeding the maximum numeric value in JavaScript (which is "only" 1.7<sup>308</sup> or so).

However, the value *is* exceeding the range of "integral precision". It is not that the wrong number is sent: rather, it is that the *literal* 12000000000002539 *can only be represented as precisely as* 12000000000002540, and thus there was *never* the correct numeric value in JavaScript. (The [range of integrals](http://www.irt.org/script/1031.htm) is about +/- 2<sup>53</sup>.)

This is an interesting phenomena of using [*a double relative-precision*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) (binary64 in IEEE-754 speak) type to store all numeric values, including integers:

```
12000000000002539 === 12000000000002540 // true
```

The maximum significant number of decimal digits that be precisely stored as a numeric value is 15 (15.95, really). In the above, there are 17 significant digits, so some of *the least-significant information is silently lost*. In this case, *as* the JavaScript parser/engine reads in the literal value.

The only safe way to handle integral numbers of this magnitude in JavaScript is to use a string literal or to break it down in another fashion (e.g. a custom numeric type or a ["bigint library"](http://www.khjk.org/log/2010/nov/jsbigint.html)). However, *I recommend just using a string*, as it is human readable, relatively compact (only two extra characters in JSON), and doesn't require special serialization. Since the value is just an "id" in this case, I hope that math does not need to be performed upon it :)

Happy coding.

Comment: It's worth noting that JSON ([RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627)) makes no guarantees about what range of numbers JSON consumers are required to be able to represent so the answer may be different for other clients: "An implementation may set limits on the range of numbers."