# Simple Regex NOT on multidimensional JSON string

Tags: php, regex

So i will provide this simple example of json string covering most of my actual string cases:

```
"time":1430702635,\"id\":\"45.33\",\"state\":2,"stamp":14.30702635,
```

And i'm trying to do a preg replace to the numbers from the string, to enclose them in quotes, except the numbers which index is already quoated, like in my string - '\state\':2
    My regex so far is

```
 preg_replace('/(?!(\\\"))(\:)([0-9\.]+)(\,)/', '$2"$3"$4',$string);
```

The rezulting string i'm tring to obtain in this case is having the "\state\" value unquoted, skipped by the regex, because it contains the \" ahead of :digit,

```
"time":"1430702635",\"id\":\"45.33\",\"state\":2,"stamp":"14.30702635",
```

Why is the '\state\' number replaced also ?

Tried on https://regex101.com/r/xI1zI4/1 also ..

New edit:

So from what I tried,

```
  (?!\\")
```

is not working !!

If I'm allowed, I will leave this unanswered in case someone else does know why.

My solution was to use this regex, instead of NOT, I went for yes ..

```
$string2 = preg_replace('/(\w":)([0-9\.]+)(,)/', '$1"$2"$3',$string);
```

Thank you.

Comment: cant you just decode it first then cast all elements to string, then reencode again

Comment: No as I would loose big integers  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663298/json-transfer-of-bigint-12000000000002539-is-converted-to-12000000000002540

Comment: Here's a solution for your current case but I think this could be done much better... `preg_replace('~(("time":)([0-9.]+),|("stamp":)([0-9.]+),)~', '$2$4"$3$5",',$string);`

Comment: @chris85 my string is just an example, my actual string is like 100kb long and can't cover everything with literal words .. I think I should reformulate my problem..

Comment: Is there something consistent about all numbers that should have quotes? Greater than 5 decimal places, starts with 143, etc.?

Comment: @chris85 - my example string covers most of the cases, i'm interested why the (?!\\\") is not skipping the \state\" ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?!\\")` is a negative lookahead, which generally isn't useful at the very beginning of a regular expression.  In your particular regex, it has no effect at all: the expression `(?!(\\\"))(\:)` means "empty string not followed by slash-quote, then a colon" which is equivalent to just trying to match a colon by itself.

I think what you were trying to accomplish is a negative lookbehind, which has a slightly different syntax in PCRE: `(?<!\\")`.  Making this change seems to match what you want: https://regex101.com/r/xI1zI4/2