# Response data is changed when calling web api using ajax request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api2, bit

I have a web api which is returning a list(each item consists of bit values).
But when I see response from client side in console, I found that the bit value is changed.

For example if I have 36028797018963968 bit value in database then it is changed to 36028797018963970.

This is happening only for this bit value. In a list of 5 values only the above mentioned value is changing. The remaining are coming fine.

I have never seen this type of behaviour before, so I am not sure what else I should be posting here. Ask me if you need anything else.

Comment: How is the data being transferred? json? are you converting the value from string to integer or something?

Comment: @Kevin B The data is being transferred as json. I am not converting it anywhere. The value is of type long in my API. When I put a log in my ajax success call I am getting this wierd values. Now when I try parsing the data into XML it is working fine. I don't understand why it didn't work before when I am returning it in json.  

        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation for integer values in Json. But Javascript has boundaries.

[JSON transfer of bigint: 12000000000002539 is converted to 12000000000002540?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663298/json-transfer-of-bigint-12000000000002539-is-converted-to-12000000000002540)