# BigInteger Values are changing when converting to JSON Object

Tags: java, json, long-integer, bigint

I have a maximum number for Long(9223372036854775807), but when I'm retrieving this value, it's showing correctly in the back-end (Java). However, when it comes to the response in the Ajax call, the value is coming as 9223372036854776000

Comment: @ShubhWIP Yeah that make sense. cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON transfer of bigint: 12000000000002539 is converted to 12000000000002540?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663298/json-transfer-of-bigint-12000000000002539-is-converted-to-12000000000002540)